# Multiple upload forms using PHP, AJAX and jQuery on single page doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

Does anyone know of a jQuery-AJAX image uploader, where I can have *multiple instances* of the form on the same page?

Let me elaborate on my situation! I have a front end page, where a user can change his profile, when the page loads, it loops through all the content-type rows in the database.

I need to apply an image upload form for every type of `img`.

The problem is, that every plugin I have tried will only allow me to have *1 upload form per page*, but I need one for user profile image, one for signature image one for ... as defined by the content elements in the table.

Example:

```
<form id='upload' method='post' action='script.php?val=profilepic' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <div id='drop'>
     Drop Here
     <a>Browse</a>
     <input type='file' name='upl' multiple />
   </div>
   <input style='visibility:hidden' id='".$var2['id']."' value='page_session_weo' />
   <ul style='display:none'>
     <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
   </ul>
</form>

<form id='upload' method='post' action='script.php?val=sigpic' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <div id='drop'>
     Drop Here
     <a>Browse</a>
     <input type='file' name='upl' multiple />
   </div>
   <input style='visibility:hidden' id='".$var2['id']."' value='page_session_weo' />
   <ul style='display:none'>
     <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
   </ul>
</form>

<form id='upload' method='post' action='script.php?val=homepagepic' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <div id='drop'>
     Drop Here
     <a>Browse</a>
     <input type='file' name='upl' multiple />
   </div>
   <input style='visibility:hidden' id='".$var2['id']."' value='page_session_weo' />
   <ul style='display:none'>
     <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
   </ul>
</form>
```

Below is the picture to get better understanding of my problem:

[image: case]

Any help or advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you searched yourself yet?

Comment: the `quotes - "` before $str5 are missing. I hope thats not your problem.?

Comment: using the same id for different forms in not good at all. By the way your code contains some errors too.

Comment: He doesn't want to use same id for different forms, I think. It looks, that he wants different instances of the same uploader?

Comment: Ilia Rostovtsev is correct, and yes I have searched and no the quotes is not an issue, this is just example code

Comment: David, you must just tie your script to the different ids! You can't have same ids on one page. It will not work this way. Try to use form `id='upload1'`, `id='upload2'` and `id='upload3'` and correspond it with the init function (or in whatever way you have to load it)

Comment: Ilia Rostovtsev I agree with you, can you provide an example of such an uploader as the two that i have looked at (which have drag and drop (not supported by uploadify)) have massive javascript files linked to 1 element making it hard to do a .each init(#id+counter)

Comment: UploadiFive (jQuery+HTML5) version of Uplodify supports drag and drop function! Example: http://vimeo.com/40923687. Please take a look at the list of features: http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/ I used it for my project - it's as flexible as it gets. In my answer, you can see that two different examples of codes initialize two different instances of the uploader! Have you tried to use UploadiFive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could! I would recommend *[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/about/)* script that works very well. It supports multiple file uploads and multiple instances of the uploader.

Example:

```
$(function() {
    $("#file_upload_1").uploadify({
        height        : 30,
        swf           : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        uploader      : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
        width         : 120
    });
});
```

and

```
$(function() {
    $("#file_upload_2").uploadify({
        height        : 30,
        swf           : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        uploader      : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
        width         : 120
    });
});
```

In your case your uploader doesn't work simply because you have multiple ids with the same name on the page. It's invalid. Look at the example about, it represents correct idea that you would have to implement using your code or to use the other script to do it!

Comment: I looked into it and yes it would solve the problem but it has no drag and drop which is a requirement

Comment: David, UploadiFive ($5 version of Uploadify has no Flash and runs only on HTML5+jQuery) has drag and drop functionality! Please take a closer look to onDrop function of UploadiFive, here: http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadifive/ondrop/. You can also see it in action here: http://vimeo.com/40923687. I really was trying hard to sort out the best uploader, when was making it for my project - UloadiFive was certainly the best, 5-6 months ago at least and I believe still is!

Comment: David, my pleasure! ;) Good luck with your development!

Answer (score 1):

**Important: User Ray Nicholus comments below that the iframe "trick" mentioned in this answer only works in IE9. For all modern browsers, XHR2 (ajax) requests are used to upload the files.**

Not sure if this is what you're looking for:

Multiple file upload plugin with progress-bar, drag-and-drop.

The [Widen/fine-uploader](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader) AJAX file upload plug-in allows users to upload multiple files without having to refresh the page. In addition, you can use any element to trigger the file selection window. The plug-in creates a semi-transparent file input screen over the button you specify, so when a user clicks on the button, the normal file selection window is shown. After the user selects a file, the plug-in submits the form that contains the file input to an iFrame. So it isn’t true AJAX but provides the same user experience.

It has been turned into a commercial product: [fineuploader.com](http://fineuploader.com)

[Github project is here](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader)

Comment: The iframe "trick" you mentioned only occurs in Fine Uploader in IE9 and older.  For all modern browsers, XHR2 (ajax) requests are used to upload the files.